# How to download offline maps with SKMaps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

I tried downloading offline maps with `SKMaps`.
At first I'd like to create a region from a self made `SKTPackage` like this:

```
SKTPackage* packageToDownload;
packageToDownload.type = 3;
packageToDownload.packageCode = @"DEBY";
SKTDownloadObjectHelper* region = [SKTDownloadObjectHelper downloadObjectHelperWithSKTPackage:packageToDownload];
```

Unfortunately the region is empty and every attempt to add `packageToDownload.languages` led to a crash. What can I do to initiate an offline map download with only the `packageCode` and `packageType`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How to set up the download component: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/iosTools#sec11

Comment: I read that, still not getting it

Comment: I've reported the question to the Scout developers

Answer (score 1):

In the provided code snippet, the packageToDownload object is never initialized. Replace the first line with:

```
SKTPackage *packageToDownload = [[SKTPackage alloc] init];
```